# How to retrieve data-attribute value of which is an array of objects with jquery

Tags: javascript

My data-attribute looks something like this:

```
data-image="[object Object],[object Object] "
```

Comment: Can you include HTML at Question? How is `data-*` attribute set?

Comment: Please add more details to the question. What is the question here ? What are you trying to do and how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only string/number can be stored in attributes. So just store the src of the image if you want to store image details. If for some reason you want to store an object, convert it to string first and then later when you retrieve it, convert to object.

```
//Convert to String 
var mystring = JSON.stringify(myobject); // store this in the attribute. 

//Convert to Object while retrieving 
var myobj = JSON.parse(mystring);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the `data-*` attribute is set at HTML use valid `JSON` for the value, `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` to set and get the `data-*` attribute value as a JavaScript object. You can get and set the HTML `data-*` attribute using `HTMLElement.dataset`

```js
console.log(
  JSON.parse(
    document.querySelector("div").dataset.image
  )
)
```

```html
<!-- set `data-*` attribute value as valid `JSON` -->
<div data-image='[{"a":123}, {"b":456}]'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually when you retrieve this, you will get only string with value `[object Object],[object Object]`. You keep your data in the `data-attribute` with wrong syntax. Try first make your value of `data-image` into `JSON` format and then keep in the `data-image` attribute. After that you can retrieve your data via (see comments)

```js
const dataArray = [ { name: 'Name1' }, { name: 'Name2' } ];
const div = $('#div');

div.data('image', JSON.stringify(dataArray)); // keep the attribute as string 

const retrievedDataImageAsJSON = div.data('image'); // retrieve the data attribute as string
const dataObj = JSON.parse(retrievedDataImageAsJSON); // parse from JSON into JS objects.

console.log(dataObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div' data-image>

</div>
```